# Randomly assign groups in excel with equal Gender split

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet taken from a SQL query that contains four columns: ID, First Name, Last Name, Family ID.

I have a requirement to split 187 people (98 male, 89 female) into four seperate "communities", and then subdivided into four "groups" per community. Each group needs to be split as near to 50/50 by gender as possible.

There is an additional requirement to ensure that people of the same family (duplicate Family ID) are kept in the same community (though not necessarily group).

Is anyone aware of anything within Excel that would make this possible?

Comment: Is there no field for gender?

Comment: I believe you mean as close to the incremental M/F ratio (98/89 in your case) as possible. I further think that we should first fill up the communities with families then remove them from the smallest (unique family ID, two with the same ID etc.) until we reach the agreed M and F numbers (24, 22). We then could fill them back with preferably individuals. The solution is non-deterministc.